# Moving loop in stationary magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, electrical-engineering

So according to my understanding, the emf at time $t_1$ and $t_2$ should be the same. However at $t_3$, although there is no emf from induction, there is motional emf, which induces a current. So how do I compare the magnitude of $t_3$ to the previous times? Also, does that mean when analysing $t_1$ and $t_2$, I have to include motional emf as well as induced emf in my calculations?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faraday law of Induction and motional emf are pretty much the same. thinking it in terms of faradays law gives 0 and in terms of motional emf there's zero. Faraday law includes motional emf in the concept of flux change due to motion, AND due to transformer emf (changing magnetic field) the description of flux already encorporates motional emf. if it were to be moved inside the B field. there would be  a net zero magnetic force on this object

for the t3 the magnetic field on the top and bottom both point perpendicular to dl so are zero and the left and right point down  but cancel eachother out leaving net zero work done